# Does Biopython support Python 3.2?

Tags: python, biopython

Biopython's website mentioned that it requires Python up to version 2.7, but does not state explicitly whether Python 3+ support exists.

Is there any way to use Biopython with Python 3.2?

See: http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/install/Installation.html#sec7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit August 29 2015**

Biopython 1.65 is fully compatible with Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, and 3.4

If you're using Windows, there are officially released and supported 32-bit installation packages packages on the main website, and unofficial 64-bit installers here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#biopython

Otherwise, you can download and build biopython yourself, or use `pip` or `easy_install` to do so.

See: http://biopython.org/wiki/Download

Comment: That was correct at the time. More recently, a 32bit windows installer was included for Python 3.2 with Biopython 1.60 (but Christoph Gohlke's page is still currently the only option for a pre-built 64bit Windows NumPy and Biopython installer).

Comment: @peterjc Thanks for the update, I edited my answer to reflect the new beta package for Python 3.2.